# React hooks to get response headers

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get response headers from an API in my project. I've been using the following format to get all of my other JSON data:

```
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${state.source.api}wp/v2/posts`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setMyData(data);
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(myData);
```

The above returns all of my WP posts as it should, I'm just trying to update this to also get the Headers, which contains X-WP-Total. I've tried out some other examples online with no luck.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this -- without Axios?

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out myself. Here is the updated code if anyone else runs into this:

```
  const [postCount, setPostCount] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${state.source.api}wp/v2/posts`).then((response) => {
      setPostCount(response.headers.get("X-WP-Total"));
    });
  }, []);
  console.log(postCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one method, which is should work, is to get header name with `-` char using square brackets after headers:

```
const [postCount, setPostCount] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${state.source.api}wp/v2/posts`).then((response) => {
      setPostCount(response.headers['X-WP-Total');
    });
  }, []);
console.log(postCount);
```